# Toast.. on android

Tags: java, android

Hello can you please help me.. I would like to add toast on my code.. But I dont know where to put it.. I just want toast to appear after pressing button..

```
public class Question1 extends Fragment{

RadioButton q1a2;
Button btn1;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question1, null);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    q1a2 = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.q1a2);
    btn1 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnq1);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

            if (q1a2.isChecked()){
                editor.putInt("answer_value", 1);
            } else {
                editor.putInt("answer_value", 0);
            }
            editor.commit();
        }

    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Inside

```
onClick(View v){
// some else
// showing toast
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

On click display toast

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button pressed",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
         ...//rest of the code
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 1):

To Display [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Do like this on your onClick of the button listener

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

   /* here ->*/  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily [add a Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) inside the OnClickListener. When the listener is invoked, the code inside `onClick()` is executed, so you could modify this to include your toast:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick() executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ...
    }
});
```

Bear in mind that `Toast.makeText()` simply creates a new Toast object. Invoking `show()` on that object will cause it to appear. The duration of the toast can be controlled using `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

I'd suggest getting a little more acquainted with Android by understanding how events and listeners work.